# Why do we need coroutines in python?

Tags: python, coroutine

I've heard about co-routines long ago, but never used them. As I know, co-routines are similar to generators.

Why do we need co-routines in Python?

Comment: You should be able to find an answer to that using google. Any answer here would likely be subjective and lengthy. Thats why such questions are considered off topic for SO.

Comment: I agree. I'd like to get kind of real example where I can use it.

Comment: I think David Beasley (dabeaz) is one of the main proponents of coroutines in python. His blog or pycon talks might be a good place to start.

Comment: They are another useful tool to solve problems.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Generator](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/generators.html#generators) uses yield to return values. Python generator functions can also consume values using a `(yield)` statement. In addition two new methods on generator objects, `send()` and `close()`, create a framework for objects that consume and produce values. Generator functions that define these objects are called [coroutines](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/coroutines.html).

Coroutines consume values using a `(yield)` statement as follows:

```
value = (yield)
```

With this syntax, execution pauses at this statement until the object's send method is invoked with an argument:

```
coroutine.send(data)
```

Then, execution resumes, with value being assigned to the value of data. To signal the end of a computation, we shut down a coroutine using the `close()` method. This raises a GeneratorExit exception inside the coroutine, which we can catch with a try/except clause.

The example below illustrates these concepts. It is a coroutine that prints strings that match a provided pattern.

```
def match(pattern):
    print('Looking for ' + pattern)
    try:
        while True:
            s = (yield)
            if pattern in s:
                print(s)
    except GeneratorExit:
        print("=== Done ===")
```

We initialize it with a pattern, and call `__next__()` to start execution:

```
m = match("Jabberwock")
m.__next__()
Looking for Jabberwock
```

The call to `__next__()` causes the body of the function to be executed, so the line "Looking for jabberwock" gets printed out. Execution continues until the statement `line = (yield)` is encountered. Then, execution pauses, and waits for a value to be sent to m. We can send values to it using `send()`.

Comment: I like your post, but maybe it could also eleborate on why/when they are better than a function or an object?

Comment: You can also omit the m.__next__() call if you decorate your function with @coroutine as described briefly here https://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/coroutine.py

Comment: Can you elaborate on the _next__()? My problem is, why does python not execute the function until it reaches yield? What triggers this kind of behaviour? Is python scanning the whole function and checks if it sees 'yield' and then decides match("") is not a function call, but sort of a closure? I am a bit puzzled.

Comment: You haven't mention when and why do we use coroutines? You just gave steps to execute them..

Answer (score 4):

Coroutines are similar to generators with a few differences. The main differences are:

1. generators are data producers
2. coroutines are data consumers

[You may have a look here for details](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/coroutines.html)